# escape space for the file path in ajax url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've my file in my local machine, path of the file is:

C:\Users\HADOOP MACHINE\Documents\test.txt

I've to pass the file in ajax call in url but in the path there is space. How can I escape the space in ajax url.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "C:\\Users\\HADOOP MACHINE\\Documents\\test.json",
    dataType: "json",           
    success: function(data)
    {
    alert(data);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
}
```

Comment: You need to have a look at the same origin policy restrictions when accessing file system resources via ajax

Comment: I tried:

C:\\Users\\HADOOP%20MACHINE\\Documents\\test.json

but not worked.